# How to display the exact query in the output section of a stored procedure when using 'Dynamic SQL' and 'Bind variables' in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-11g-r2, plsql, dynamic-sql

I have a Procedure as you can see below. In this procedure I have a `dynamic query`which is `qry` variable and I'm using `Bind variable` in order to eliminate the risk of injection and improve performance:

```
create or replace procedure first_test(i_tx varchar2, o_count out number) is

qry varchar2(1000);
begin
    qry := 'select count(*) from z_test_a where c_num = :1';

    execute immediate qry
    into o_count
    using i_tx;

   dbms_output.put_line(qry);
end;
```

what I want to know is that , how I can see the exact `qry` after `using i_tx`. What I mean is that if the input parameter is `i_tx = 2` how I can see this `select count(*) from z_test_a where c_num = 2` in the output section of the procedure so that I can debug the code in case of error? Is this even possible to see the exact query? In this procedure , what I'm getting right now in the output page is :`select count(*) from z_test_a where c_num = :1`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should output the query *before* you use it (in case it throws an error).

Comment: @MichaelKutz Could you please give me an example? How can I see the query with the input parameter that is passed to the procedure?

Comment: You've misunderstood how Bind *variables* work. **TL;DR** spit out the value of you Bind values also. done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would `REPLACE` do any good? See line #6 and result of `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure first_test(i_tx varchar2, o_count out number) is
  2    qry varchar2(1000);
  3  begin
  4      qry := 'select count(*) from z_test_a where c_num = :1';
  5
  6      dbms_output.put_line(replace(qry, ':1', i_tx));    --> like this
  7
  8      execute immediate qry into o_count using i_tx;
  9  end;
 10  /

Procedure created.

SQL> declare
  2    l_cnt number;
  3  begin
  4    first_test(1, l_cnt);
  5  end;
  6  /
select count(*) from z_test_a where c_num = 1               --> result you want, I guess

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```